# How can I set a different serialized name and deserialized name in MVC?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a class with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes on it. I set the Name on the `Origin` property to be `custom variables` as that's what the api I'm calling provides. The problem is, that only solves the deserialization of the object. When it comes time to serialize the object, I want to serialize the `Origin` property as `origin`.

```
[DataContract]
public class Request
{
    ...

    [DataMember(Name = "custom variables")]
    public Origin Origin { get; set; }
}
```

For example, I want to deserialize this:

```
{
    ...

    "custom variables": {
        "url": "URL_HERE",
        "origin": "ORIGIN_HERE"
    }
}
```

and turn it into this upon serialization:

```
{
    ...

    "origin": {
        "url": "URL_HERE",
        "origin": "ORIGIN_HERE"
    }
}
```

> How can I do this? Is there any way to do it without writing a custom serializer for all of the properties on the object?

Comment: Serializing under a different name then deserializing breaks the whole idea of serializing. You should use 2 different classes instead or/and use a object mapper

Comment: Instead of DataMember try using [JsonProperty("custom variables")]

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#customize-individual-property-names

You must decorate the property with the JsonPropertyName decorator (from the System.Text.Json.Serialization namespace).

In example:

```
public class WeatherForecastWithPropertyNameAttribute {
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureCelsius { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("Wind")]
    public int WindSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

Serialized/deserialized json:

```
{
  "Date": "2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00",
  "TemperatureCelsius": 25,
  "Summary": "Hot",
  "Wind": 35
}
```